# Manipulating data inside of map function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

For some reason, when using `toLocaleString` from within this map, only one of the `payment.amount`'s come back formatted as currency.

```
{props.paymentDates.map((payment, index) => (
  <tr key={"payment-" + index}>
    <td>{index + 1}</td>
    <td>{moment(payment.date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}</td>
    <td>
      {payment.amount.toLocaleString("en-US", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "USD",
      })}
    </td>
  </tr>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've now fixed this, after using the new ES6 method:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { style: "currency", currency: "USD" }).format(payment.amount);
```